# Remotely access my RPI

Tags: pi-4, ssh

My company is building a physical product powered by a Raspberry PI 4. This product will be shipped out to different physical locations (eg. hotels, airports, stores) and connected to that location's private WiFi network.

Without needing network/router adjustments, what are some ways I can remotely access our RPI's terminal from our own networks?

Security is a huge factor:

1. We don't want attackers to be able to connect to the RPIs... A whitelisted IP system? Pretty standard practice.
2. If, say a physical attacker were to tamper with the RPI--when I connect to the RPI from my home network, I don't want my machine's files to be accessible by whatever tampering the attacker put in place. (Not sure if this is even possible, but I'm sure you get what I mean).

I'm familiar with Linux systems (specifically Ubuntu), but I am quite new to Raspberry Pi in general.

Comment: `I'm familiar with Linux systems` - good, because Raspberry Pi runs Linux (debian based, same as Ubuntu) - `quite new to Raspberry Pi` - does that matter? it's a Linux system based on debian, the hardware is irrelevant to your requirements